# How to add value to textarea of 2D checkboxes when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, 2d, checkbox

I want to pass the value of checked checkboxes of 2d array through ajax. also if checked parent category and some of its subcategory, if again clicked on category all the subcategory unchecked... Please help

- 
  ACTIVEWEAR
- PANTS
- SHORTS
- SINGLETS
- SPORTS BRAS
- TIGHTS
- TOPS

BASICS

Answer (score 0):

use selecter class for your child nodes, then change all checkboxes values with the selecter class when clicked on parent node

example...

```
$("#parent").change(function(){
    $(".childNodes").checked = true;
});
```